# nullable nas models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Para que serve o nullable em uma model? Por exemplo:

```
public int? ProjectId;
```

Se eu coloco desta forma estou aceitando valores nulos, certo?

E se eu colocasse a annotation required na propriedade, sendo ela required não teria como o valor ser null ou teria?

Por que razão alguem usaria isso? se há a possibilidade do valor ser nulo porque não apenas deixar sem o `?`

Answer (score 7):

Gosto de pensar em DataAnnotation`s de validação nos modelos como sendo "mensagens" destinadas ao usuário final, que indicam o que é necessário fazer para que os dados inseridos sejam considerados como corretos.

Quando um modelo possui uma propriedade cujo tipo é uma `struct` nullable (tais como `Int32?`, `DateTime?`, `Double?`, entre outros) e ao mesmo tempo possui a anotação `Required` em uma dessas propriedades, é como se o programa dissesse assim para o usuário:

> Senhor usuário, este modelo só é valido quando a propriedade P for preenchida.
>   Você pode até deixar de preencher o valor da mesma (afinal ela é nullable), mas nesse caso eu (o programa)
>   não vou salvar nada e vou mostrar uma mensagem de erro.

Para mim, todos os `DataAnnotation`s de validação servem para restringir as possibilidades do tipo de dados usado, ou seja, tornar inválidos valores possíveis para o tipo de dado.

Ao meu ver, o atributo `Required` **só deve ser aplicado em propriedades cujo tipo de dados possa ser anulado**. Ou seja, o atributo serve para tornar inválida a possibilidade que o tipo de dados dá.

**Respondendo suas questões mais diretamente:**

- > **Q:** E se eu colocasse a annotation required na propriedade, sendo ela required não teria como o valor ser null ou teria?

  - **R:** quando a propriedade é requerida o valor pode ser nulo mesmo assim... ocorre quando o usuário deixa o campo em branco, sendo que nesse caso o `ModelState` vai indicar um erro no modelo.
- > **Q:** Por que razão alguem usaria isso? se há a possibilidade do valor ser nulo porque não apenas deixar sem o `?`

  - **R:** Se o tipo da propriedade for `int` (ou qualquer outra struct) e sem `Required`, **isso implica automaticamente em um campo de preenchimento obrigatório**... é como se o `Required` estivesse lá. Nesse exemplo, se o usuário deixar o campo em branco, o valor associado ao modelo será o `int` padrão: `default(int)` que é `0`, sendo que o `ModelState` indicará que a propriedade contém um erro pois não fora preenchido.

Answer (score 6):

> [...] se há a possibilidade do valor ser nulo porque não apenas deixar sem o `?`

Um `Nullable Type` permite a possibilidade de um *não-valor* (*Null* neste caso) para um `Value Type` (ou *tipo de valor*), já que estes por padrão sempre possuem um valor - portanto a primeira parte desta pergunta não está correta.

Os seguintes tipos de valor possuem versões *Nullable*:

```
Tipo de Valor         Valor Padrão
bool                  false
byte                  0
char                  '\0'
decimal               0.0M
double                0.0D
enum                  O primeiro valor (retornado pela expressão (E)0)
float                 0.0F
int                   0
long                  0L
sbyte                 0
short                 0
uint                  0
ulong                 0
ushort                0
```

`Reference Types` (ou *tipos de referência*) podem por definição não possuir um referência, não nessessitando assim deste recurso.

Leitura complementar:

Valores padrão de Tipos de Valor
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx

Usando *Nullable Types*
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2cf62fcy(v=vs.100).aspx

Tipos de Valor e Referência
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Exato, o nullable vai ser para que você não utilize os valores default de cada tipo.

Agora o DataAnottation você vai utilizar para um controle a parte.